# What char number is □, or how to reference this in my VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

I need some VBA to find and replace any □ characters in columns A to P.

However, I am not sure how to write this character into the code for my `i` variable

```
i = 
k = vbNullString
Sheets("RefindData").Columns("A:P").Replace What:=i, replacement:=k, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
```

Comment: You can find it on Google... "Ascii Table" or things like that

Comment: Using this site: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ I am unable to locate this character

Comment: I have found some reference to unicode here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm given this information though, question still remains, how do I reference this in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA `□` is represented by

```
ChrW(&H25A1)
```

Hence **use `i = ChrW(&H25A1)` in your code**.

See [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/640488-inserting-symbol-cell-using-vba.html) for detail.

[image]